# Karaf features:addurl syntax

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

I have seen two different syntax in Karaf to add a repo, e.g.,

```
features:addurl mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-example-osgi/2.10.0/
xml/features
features:addurl mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-example-osgi/2.10.0/
xml
```

Can someone explain the difference between the 2? I believe they are both referring to a `features` file but they are in different locations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> features:addurl mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-example-osgi/2.10.0/xml

Doesn't actually work for me. BUT I think can break down what is happening.

mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-example-osgi/2.10.0 is a maven URl with an implicit 'type' and 'classifier'. The type is 'jar' and the classifier is empty, by default. Therefore it resolves to a file called camel-example-osgi-2.10.0.jar. (artifactId-version[-classifier].type)

In this case:

mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-example-osgi/2.10.0/xml is a type of 'xml' and no classifier. This resolves to a file called camel-example-osgi-2.10.0.xml, which doesn't exist.

mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-example-osgi/2.10.0/xml/features is a type of 'xml' and a classifier of 'features'. This, then, resolves to a file called camel-example-osgi-2.10.0-features.xml . We can look on the server and see that this file exists: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/camel-example-osgi/2.10.0/

I can't find good documentation for it but 'classifier' adds the -$classifier to the filename. This is how some maven artifacts have a classifier of -jdkN and -jdkM or -jdbc4 or -jdbc3 on them.

References: https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxurl/Mvn+Protocol
http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#POM_Relationships

Comment: This is correct. The diffference is simply the classifier. Both variants are possible. Basically it depends on the guy who writes the pom for the feature file.